# Powershell Import-csv without headers and where-object

Tags: powershell, csv

I have a csv file like:

```
020;1;1;1
030;1;1;1
020;1;2;1
040;1;1;1
```

Now I want to import-csv the values from the first column and value 020.

I tried:

```
Import-csv "path/to/file" | Where-Object {$_.[0] -eq "020"
```

I get a missing Value error.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have three issues there:

- The file is not comma separated, but semicolon. Use `-Delimiter ';'` in
  Import-Csv.
- The file is missing header (column names) information. Use `-Header c1,c2,c3,c4` or appropriate column names to specify those.
- Filtering should be done by column name, something like `c1 -eq '020'`

So, your full command should be:

```
Import-Csv 'path/to/file' -Header c1,c2,c3,c4 -Delimiter ';' | Where-Object c1 -eq '020'
```

Comment: Thank you, that seems to work. One last problem:
When I want to query for c1 and c3 how can I do that? 

`code  |Where-Object c1 -eq '020 -and c3 -eq '1'`
@Igor Please help

Comment: `code |? c1 -eq '020' |? c3 -eq '1'`
or
`code |? { $_.c1 -eq '020' -and $_.c3 -eq '1' }`